# ec2 instance not created for ecs cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am new to ECS 
I need Help on few of the things:

**FIRST**
I am gonna use docker images tagged according to git tags then pushed to ECR and update the task Definition. Is there any way by which i can know that which revision consists of which tag. As the revisions are numbered in a sequential manner rather than the docker image tag. And i am gonna use bitbucket pipelines to push the image then update the service.
I want this feature so that i can revert to a desired tag anytime.
Will a python script with boto3 be helpful? Can anybody help with that

**SECOND**
An EC2 instance is not launched on creating a new cluster other then t2.micro...
and then it leads to "No Container Instances were found in your cluster"
error on creating any service on that cluster. 
I checked that i have 'AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role' attached to ecsinstance Role and i explicitly added this as a policy to my IAM user. BUt still the same issue. ANy Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

For **SECOND**:

As per AWS Docs, the instances containing the Docker Images should reside in public subnet to query repositories.

I had this issue earlier and it was fixed when I changed the subnets in AutoScaling groups to public instead of private.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on public subnets. What CIDR block needs to be configured. I am using default VPC

Comment: you need to check if the subnets, in which the docker ec2 instances are present, have an `igw` present.